# Specifying what value should be returned by reflect.ValueOf

Tags: go, reflection

I have a struct such as this:

```
type Time struct {
    Time time.Time
    Valid bool
}
```

Now if I call `reflect.ValueOf()` on a `Time` struct initialized with, say `time.Now()` and `false`, I'll get the following results:

```
{2018-06-09 15:03:17.4320396 false}
```

Is there a way to alter the struct (add a method? rename the fields?) so that `reflect` would only return the `time.Time` value, but not the `bool` one ?
Kind of like what the Valuer/Scanner interface does for SQL queries, but with `reflect`.

Comment: In Go you cannot "add a method" to, or "rename the fields" of, a previously declared struct type. Not possible. Can you be more explicit in what you are actually trying to do? Maybe provide some code of the input you need to work with and the output you would like to produce?

Comment: Also, unless you change std lib's source, you cannot change the behaviour of `reflect.ValueOf`. It will always retrun a `reflect.Value` representation of the value you pass to it as the sole argument. You cannot somehow "specify" that it should return something other than what it would normally retrun. That's just not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible. Sorry.